# Is it possible to get size of a structure without padded bytes - sum of members' sizes

Tags: c++, structure, padding, sizeof

I need to check if structures were changed, for this i have static assert implemented through template technique. But for now i only have checked sizeof, but one can add something to a structure without changing sizeof.

How can i calculate sum of sizeofs of members?

```
struct A 
{
  int i;
  bool b;
};
```

I need `__sizeof(A)` to be equal to `3` that is `sizeof(A::i) + sizeof(A::b)`.

I need it to be done for big lot of structures in my project, and structures must be padded as it supposed to give the best performance.

Comment: You could try using a compiler specific pack pragma. Only downside to that approach is it isn't as portable

Comment: Do you really want that? I would consider changing the alignment of a struct a change which I want to differ from the single sizeofs of all the members.

Comment: If you know the structure of the structure you could try using offsetof() but that would only detect member variables not appended to the struct. Wouldn't detect appendage

Comment: Wouldn't this be something to detect through source control too?

Comment: You are only trying to solve 10% of the problem.  Just swap the two members to see it cannot work.

Comment: To check if structures were changed, you may use compiler library as clang to retrieve info from your structure, then compare those info with the reference one.

Comment: Good luck finding a platform with 16-bit integers. Other than that, your question title already contains the answer. That's odd.